# Detectron2 throwing "Non-existent config key" error on CPU even though the key is present in config.yaml

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, detectron

I have trained a Detectron2 model on a set of documents for layout segmentation. The training was on a CUDA enabled device with a GPU. Then I have used the *model_final.pth* and the *config.yaml* from the "outputs" folder to test the model on a different PDF document, and it works fine on my GPU system.

The problem arises on running the same program in a non-CUDA Detectron2 environment or a non-GPU Computer. The config is given as `config_path = "layout-model-training/outputs/prima/fast_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config.yaml"`

On running, it throws an error:

```
raise KeyError("Non-existent config key: {}".format(full_key))
KeyError: 'Non-existent config key: MODEL.ROI_BOX_HEAD.FED_LOSS_FREQ_WEIGHT_POWER'
```

I have checked the config.yaml and it does have:

```
MODEL:
  ROI_BOX_HEAD:
    FED_LOSS_FREQ_WEIGHT_POWER: 0.5
```

I have tried to add the `MODEL.ROI_BOX_HEAD.FED_LOSS_FREQ_WEIGHT_POWER` explicitly to the top of the config file as well, and it is still raising the `Non-existent config key: MODEL.ROI_BOX_HEAD.FED_LOSS_FREQ_WEIGHT_POWER` error.

I have tried using pre-trained models with the non-GPU systems and they perform fine, only my custom model raises the error, and that too, specifically on non-GPU devices. I am just getting started in this field with a college project. This needs to run on my teammate's non-GPU device as well.

Comment: have you tried `cfg.set_new_allowed(True)` when loading the config?